# Python: "error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required" - tried many solutions and none work

Tags: python

I'm on Win 10 Home PC, 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor.
I'm using Python 3.12.1
I'm trying to run "pip install gpt_index==0.4.24 && pip3 install langchain==0.0.142"
But I get:
"error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": [https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/"](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/%22)

- I have downloaded Visual Studio from Microsoft
- I have ticked the box under "Workloads" for "Desktop Development with C++" and installed the following:
  (https://i.stack.imgur.com/ORQHq.png)
- I then restarted, and got the same error message
- I  have gone directly to the "Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable latest supported downloads" (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170) and have downloaded and installed "Visual Studio 2015, 2017, 2019, and 2022" for the x64 architecture
- I have uninstalled all older versions of Microsoft Visual C++
- I have run "python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools" successfully
  ... and yet still I'm getting the same error message!
  Can anyone help please?

Comment: The prompt is to install the build tools. Have you tried doing that?

Comment: What is the full message you are getting? Please copy-paste the full contents of the command window to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I usually use PyCharm for when I code in Python so as an alternative solution I would recommend is to try to run your code in a different IDE. If it still gives you the same error you will know for sure if the problem is in the IDE or the OS itself. Hope this helps. Keep me posted.